# What's the difference among cpu, core and processor ? How are they related and how threads interact with them internally inside OS?

Tags: multithreading, operating-system, cpu, cpu-architecture

Lately I've been studying operating system. I'm a bit confused about how cpu, core and processors are related and what's hierarchy of threads interaction with them?

Comment: You can look up those terms on your own. If you have any question after doing this, because you don't understand something, for example, ask *specifically* about that. Currently, this question is too broad and will be closed as such.

Answer (score 0):

Your first question is straightforward:

Effectively CORE, PROCESSOR, and CPU are the same thing. That said, a CORE can be thought of a being a specialized type of CPU. Generally, CPUs these days are a single chip. However, a CPU may occupy multiple chips or ever multiple boards.

The next step beyond CPU chips was to put multiple CPUs on a single chip. In such a configuration the separate CPUs may be referred to as CORES. That give the terms MULTI-CORE CPU or MULTI-CORE PROCESSOR.

If you have two CPUs on separate chips, they operating independently of each other 
from a hardware perspective. If you have two [or more] CPUs (COREs) on a chip they may share resources, such as cache.

Intel also has used the term CORE in their Hyperthreading feature. There, the the CPU has two COREs that can execute instructions from separate thread. The COREs in this context are not full CPUs. They share common memory management with two instruction streams. This effectively limits the CPU to multiple threads from the same process. In multi-core CPU, each core could have multiple hyperthreading cores.

You second question is more complex. Ignoring Hyperthreading, threads are scheduled to execute on a single PROCESSOR/CPU/CORE. Thus a thread executes on a CORE/CPU/PROCESSOR.

In the hyperthreading model, a Process executes on a CPU and multiple threads can execute on a core.

I hope this brief introduction answers your question.

Comment: CPUs and cores are totally different entities, just like cores and hardware threads. Intel uses "thread" for their hyperthreading technology. A CPU with two cores and HT appears as four logical CPUs (can even be more, but Intel HT is two threads per core). A CPU is a single socket chip with one or more core plus all of the uncore. Each core has one or more thread of execution. Two or more CPU usually form a NUMA configuration.